# app not setup: this app is still in development mode,Switch to a registered test user or ask an app admin for

Tags: android, facebook-login

app not setup: this app is still in development mode, and you don't have access to it. Switch to a registered test user or ask an app admin for permission

Answer (score 0, accepted):

STEP 1:

In Settings -> Basic -> Contact Email. (Give your/any email)

STEP 2: in 'App Review' Tab : change

Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public? Yes